# logging response body with spray.io

Tags: scala, spray

The code below prints:

```
Testing started at 00:10 ...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58646', transport: 'socket'
00:10:10 INFO [lt-dispatcher-4] [a.e.s.Slf4jLogger        ] - Slf4jLogger started
vazzeg GET:200 OK
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58646', transport: 'socket'
```

The problem is that I don't see anywhere the word `logged` which was transferred back from the server to the client (in the test).

How can I log the content of the response ?

Code:

```
class MainSpec extends FreeSpec with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest with SpraySampleService {
  def actorRefFactory = system
  def requestMethodAndResponseStatusAsInfo(req: HttpRequest): Any => Option[LogEntry] = {
    case res: HttpResponse => Some(LogEntry(req.method + ":" + res.message.status, Logging.DebugLevel))
    case res =>  Some(LogEntry("vazzeg 2"+res))  // other kind of responses
  }
  def printRequestMethodAndResponseStatus(req: HttpRequest)(res: Any): Unit =
    println("vazzeg "+requestMethodAndResponseStatusAsInfo(req)(res).map(_.obj.toString).getOrElse(""))

  val logRequestResponsePrintln = DebuggingDirectives.logRequestResponse(LoggingMagnet(printRequestMethodAndResponseStatus))

  "The spraysample Route" - {
    "simple" in {
      Get("/") ~> logRequestResponsePrintln(complete("logged")) ~> check {
        val r=responseAs[String]
        r === "logged"

      }
    }
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
  "The spraysample Route" - {
    "simple" in {
        Get("/") ~> mapHttpResponse({x=>{println("response: "+x.toString);x}})(complete("logged")) ~> check {
        val r=responseAs[String]
        r === "logged"

      }
    }
```

prints:

```
vazzeg: HttpResponse(200 OK,HttpEntity(text/plain; charset=UTF-8,logged),List(),HTTP/1.1)
```